# Mysql Row to Column with ';' separator

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

i have a table (Catalogs) on my Mariadb 10.1

```
id   value
1    one ; two ; one
2    two ; three ; one
3    four ; five
4    one
5    four ; one
```

how do i count and group the value on Catalogs table like on the table below.

```
 result    count
    one      5
    two      2
    three    1
    four     2
    five     1
```

or this table

```
id value
1    one
1    two
1    one
2    two
2    three
2    one
3    four
3    five
4    one
5    four
5    one
```

Comment: Those darn csv's causing trouble again... Will people never learn?

Comment: You've violated basic rule of relational DB. You should have 3 tables here: `Catalogs`, `Values` ( or `Products` or whatever it is) and `CatalogValues( catalog_id, value_id)` which implements many to many association.

Comment: Will it always be one two three four five?

Comment: @sagi nope, its have dynamic value but always separated by comma

Comment: @rico: please share the original table data from where you are preparing this result. It can be done by breaking strings into rows  but its not a good way.

Comment: @dragoste: i know its violated basic rule of rational DB, but this table value is from other table. ex. from catalogsruas.tag[245], catalogruas.tag[240] its combined into one, and separated by comma

Comment: @Code-Monk that's all i can share mate, can you show me example breaking string into rows ?

Comment: @rico: check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking reference from link http://www.marcogoncalves.com/2011/03/mysql-split-column-string-into-rows/

Assuming you have table named as `table1` which contains two columns `id` and `value` and `value` column contains comma separated values.

Modified procedure:

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `explode_table`(bound VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

DECLARE id INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE value TEXT;
DECLARE occurance INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE splitted_value varchar(25);
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT table1.id, table1.value
                                     FROM table1
                                     WHERE table1.value != '';
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS table2;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table2(
`id` INT NOT NULL,
`value` VARCHAR(56) NOT NULL
) engine=memory;

OPEN cur1;
  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO id, value;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

    SET occurance = (SELECT LENGTH(value)
                             - LENGTH(REPLACE(value, bound, ''))
                             +1);
    SET i=1;
    WHILE i <= occurance DO
      SET splitted_value =
      trim((SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, bound, i),
      LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, bound, i - 1)) + 1), ';', '')));

      INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (id, splitted_value);
      SET i = i + 1;

    END WHILE;
  END LOOP;

 CLOSE cur1;

 SELECT * FROM table2;
 END
```

Comment: @Carra i cant normalize because i have big data, and that table help me to speed up my query

Answer (score 0):

A plain SQL way of doing it, which will cope with up to 100 split delimited values (easily expanded to cope with more if necessary):-

```
SELECT result, COUNT(id)
FROM
(
    SELECT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, ' ; ', tens.anum * 10 + units.anum + 1), ' ; ', -1) AS result
    FROM Catalogs
    CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT 1 AS anum UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0) units
    CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT 1 AS anum UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0) tens
    WHERE LENGTH(value) - LENGTH(REPLACE(value, ';', '')) >= ( tens.anum * 10 + units.anum)
) sub0
GROUP BY result
```